# Android: Help on the design of a people managr

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

In my main activity, I have a `ListView`.

I have two `List`s, 1 is a list of `People` and 1 is a list of `Group`s.
Both lists are being fed their data from their respective `SQLite database`.

To display these two Lists, I am saying `ListView.setAdapter(PeopleAdapter)` and `ListView.setAdapter(GroupAdapter)` where the adapters are just ListView Adapters that extend `BaseAdapter` and override the relevant methods etc.

What I am trying to do is change the `Group` view from a normal listview to an `ExpandableListView` so that when I click a `Group`, `People` will appear right in the `ListView`

What is the best way to achieve this?

So far I have tried changing my `GroupsAdapter` to extend `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and use that adapter but its just not working out with only 1 `ListView` in my activity because the `ListView` can't set a `ListView` adapter and a `ExpandableListView` too. It took me a long time but I just ended up reverting all my changes because it just wasnt working that way I wanted it to.

Any help on the design on how to accomplish what I want would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: crudely drawn picture of the kind of thing im looking for. Pressing the People and Groups button doesnt start a new activity, it just sets another adapter, one with a list view and one with an expandable list view.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right. Do you want an ExpandableListView where the parents (views to be clicked to expand the list) are the groups and the childs are the list of people belonging to each group?

Comment: @PXDeveloper Yes that is alot of what i want. Please see my edit for more details. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several `ExpandableListView` examples out there. I.e., you could check this one:

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/

The main part of an ExpandableListView is its adapter. In the example above it's `ExpandableListAdapter` and it extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

In your `ExpandableListAdapter` you need two lists:

-The first one is called the `group list` (parents), and in your case it should be the list of groups. I.e:

```
ArrayList<String> groups;
```

-The second one is called the `child list`, and you should have a list of childs for each element in the first list (a list of people for each group). There are several ways to do it. I.e, you can use an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` where the `ArrayList` in the position 0 is the list of people belonging to the group in the position 0, and so on.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> children;

public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}
```

You could also use a `Map` mapping an `ArrayList` of people to each group name (`String`):

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> children;

public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children.get(groups.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}
```

In the example I provided above they use a `Map`.

The way to structure your lists depends on you and the way you retrieve the data from the database.

You have to implement all the needed functions from `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. Keep in mind that groups are the "parents" (in your case, groups), and children are the elements of each group (in your case, people). If you understand this I think it should be easy to follow the example I provided above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am going to start implementing it, and see where it leads. I'll get back to you when I'm finished/stuck.

Comment: after much thought, I've decided to change my design because this expandable listview is interfering with too much other stuff. However your answer was still good and it made me learn alot about expandablelistviews which ill definitely use in the future, thanks :) Ill give you the bounty etc as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but trying new stuff is how you learn about Android :) Good luck with your app!